# SQL convert nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I have a table with a column `Quantity`; in the original table this column is defined as `nvarchar(100)` so I need to cast it as float to be able to do some analysis:

```
CAST([Quantity] AS FLOAT) AS Quantity
```

The issue is that I have some values which can not be converted to float like `No-Quantity`, `Return` etc. I to have filter to exclude these values and then convert rest to float.On option is use where clause:

```
WHERE Quantity IN ('Return', 'Sales')
```

This is not the best way since if we have anew values in the original table then I need to figure out what it is and add it to the where clause.

I am wondering is there is better way to identify non-convertible values?

Comment: use `try_convert` in sql server, which returns `null` if the value can't be converted.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any database, you can use `cast()` and something like this:

```
(case when quantity not in ('No-Quantity', 'Return', . . .)
      then CAST([Quantity] as float)
 end) as Quantity
```

The `in` list would be the list of known string values.

You can also do a fast-and-dirty check like this:

```
(case when left(quantity, 1) between '0' and '1'
      then CAST([Quantity] as float)
 end) as Quantity
```

(Note:  you may need to use `substr()` or `substring()` instead of `left()`.)

And, in general, any specific database has specific functions that can help with the conversion, such as `try_convert()` mentioned in a comment.

Comment: I am trying to convert NVARCHAR to Float using `Select  CAST(col1 as float) New_col1 from table1`. I get **Error converting data type nvarchar to float.**

Comment: @Duffer . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a question, with ample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Comment: I thought it was relevant to this post so posted in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

*If* your SQL Server supports `TRY_CONVERT`, this could provide a nice solution:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT (float, [Quantity]) ...
```

will give you the converted values or NULL depending on the input.  This could be helpful if you don't have strict control over the data.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (if you can't use `TRY_CONVERT`)

```
SELECT CAST(quantity AS float)
FROM myTable
WHERE IsNumeric(quantity) = 1 AND quantity IS NOT NULL
```